# RSA in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rsa

I am trying to decrypt a RSA string from my server-side.
While running the code from the local server it's work great,
but when deploying the app to GAE the method return an empty string (not null).

(The string input is a BASE64 representation of the binary data to be decrypted)

This is my code:

```
private static String decrypt(String pwd) {
    byte[] input = Base64.decode(pwd);


    try {
        rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        return null;
    }

    KeyFactory keyFactory;
    try {
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }

    String modString = "*********";
    String privateExponentString = "*********";

    RSAPrivateKeySpec prvKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(modString), new BigInteger(privateExponentString));
    RSAPrivateKey prvKey;


    try {
        prvKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(prvKeySpec);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, prvKey);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] cipherText;
    try {
        cipherText = rsaCipher.doFinal(input);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return new String(cipherText);
}
```

I did a little debugging on the server-side while running remotely.
I found out that the function:

```
rsaCipher.doFinal(input);
```

return an byte array while every item contains '0'.

Please Advice,

Thank you and best regards,
Noam Cohen

Comment: First of all you should not be ignoring exceptions (catching them and returning null). You should at least log the error to know what actually happened.

Comment: Thank you. In the version of code I've uploaded I removed the error handling code to make the code more easy to understand and added "return null"'s just for the compiler to accept the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error, the output string is always 128 bits long, and the desired unencrypted string is at the end while all other bytes are (null, ASCII code 0). Google log doesn't show all the string and it looks like its empty.
I am just looping every char in the output string and copy to my string every char with ASCII code different from 0.

I hope this will help someone,
Noam

Answer (score 0):

The `new String(byteArray)` uses default JVM encoding to decode the byte array into string. On AppEngine it's curiously US-ASCII.

If your original content is in UTF-8, try using `new String(cipherText), "UTF-8"`

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still receiving an empty string? Do you have any other idea? Appreciate your help.